# How to set baud rate permanently in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, raspberrypi

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspi 3. There are two USB serial devices connected to read power meters via infraread signal.

The reading of the power meters works like a charm when I set the baud rate of the serial devices to `9600 8N1` via minicom:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

However, when I restart the raspi, the baud rate is reset every time to `11520 8N1`.

Setting the baud rate via

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 cs8 -cstopb -parenb
```

doesn't work, as this sets the boud rate only for the current session as far as I could figure out. And the devies are read via Cron Jobs.

To be honest, I don't have really a clue what I'm doing there with minicom that it always works after starting the program and setting the baud rate.

I  want to persist the boud rate setting somewhere in the system so that I don't have to set it every time when I restart the raspi.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You cannot "persist" this setting. You will need to set it every time you boot. However, as the system boots, it discovers its hardware, it creates `udev` events. Start with `man udev`.